# How to Make synchronous request using NSOperationQueue?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I newbie for developing the ios application, I am trying to connect https web server, I had faced issue I am not able to connect the self signed certficate, so I have searched net In that I have followed below given code its working fine. but its working asynchronous mode.so I need until complete the task wait and return the data.Please gave any idea?/

```
func requestAsynChronousData(request: NSURLRequest)->NSData? {
    let data: NSData? = nil
    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue:NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){ (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
      if error == nil {
        print("RESULTTTT\(data)")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
    return data;
}

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential?) -> Void) {
    print("WAITING!!!!!!!!!!!!!COMPLETIONHANDLER")
    completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential, NSURLCredential(forTrust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
}
```

Comment: Unless you are doing this on a secondary thread, you should not *ever* do synchronous URL requests.  You're basically guaranteed to get rejected from the app store if you do, because iOS automatically kills apps that block the main thread for more than a few seconds, and an HTTP timeout takes up to 90 seconds.  Anything that can be done synchronously can also be done asynchronously.  You just have to design around it.  For example, instead of writing a function that returns a value, you might write a function that takes a block and passes the value to that block when the request completes.

Answer (score 0):

You need add `dispatch_semaphore_create` to you code like below

```
func requestAsynChronousData(request: NSURLRequest)->NSData? {
    let data: NSData? = nil
    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()

    let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)

    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue:NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){ (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

      if error == nil {
        print("RESULTTTT\(data)")
      }

      dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
    }
    task.resume()

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    return data;
}
```

but this way will block your main thread while your completion handler will done

Comment: Hi Its not working. still waiting.. it will not return data

Comment: did your completion block call?

Comment: it ti called the dispatch_semaphore_signal should work and send signal

Comment: Yes, got answer its working.. instead of need to change delegateQueue:NSOperationQueue.mainQueue() to delegateQueue:nil

Comment: Yes, so if the solution is right, please mark your question as answered

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

```
func requestAsynChronousData(request: NSURLRequest)->NSData? {
let data: NSData? = nil
let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue:nil)
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){ (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if error == nil {
    data=taskData
    print("RESULTTTT\(data)")
    }
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
}
task.resume()
dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
return data; 
}

func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential?) -> Void) {
print("WAITING!!!!!!!!!!!!!COMPLETIONHANDLER")
completionHandler(NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition.UseCredential, NSURLCredential(forTrust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could set the maximum number of operations on your queue to 1.

```
let operationQueue = NSOperationQueue()
operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1

let session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue:operationQueue)
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){ (data: NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

  if error == nil {
    print("RESULTTTT\(data)")
  }
}

operationQueue.addOperation(task)
```

This will force the operations in this queue to act synchronously without using semaphores which will allow NSOperationQueue to clean up itself